# Google Script help to create new folder in drive with name drawn from two cells in one row

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a new folder in google drive using a script attached to a button in google sheets. I have done things so far that I am able to create a folder. My request is for help to name the folder using values from two cells in the row. For example: Serial No and Customer Name are two columns in the sheet. So in that row when I click on the create folder button, I want the name of the folder created to be Serial No-Customer Name (say, 1-XYZ). I have searched a lot online for this but have not got anything that I can use. I am not a techie so I am finding it difficult to understand how this can be done. Any help is welcome. Thanks, Ravi

Comment: Kindly include your current script. First of all, you might need to add checkboxes. Because the script have no way to know what button is clicked and where it is. So you need an identifier and that is where the checkbox will enter. And then, you need to identify the row on which a checkbox is ticked, then use that row number to supply in your function and have it get the values for that row.

Comment: Thanks ASYntuBU for your response. Yes as mentioned in my comment below, I now have to work on identifying each row. will keep learning ...thanks again

Comment: Im on the phone right now so i cant provide an exact answer. But once im back and still havent got an accepted one, will provide later a script and modofication of what i have recommended

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that serial no is in A and customer name in B, and a chec k box anywhere in the same row

[image]

To  create a new folder and name it

```
function onSpeEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var cel = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (cel.getValue()==true){
    var name =  sheet.getRange('A' + cel.getRow()).getValue() + '_' + sheet.getRange('B' + cel.getRow()).getValue()
    if (name!=''){
      sheet.getRange('F' + cel.getRow()).setValue(getFolderId(name))
    }
  }
}

function getFolderId(name){
  var id;
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name);
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    id = folder.getId(); }
  else {
    var folder = DriveApp.createFolder(name);
    id = folder.getId();
  }
  return id;
}
```

therefore I also prevent creating the same folder twice with the same name

put an installable trigger on onSpeEdit

you will get back the folder id in column F

[DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)

[installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Thanks So much Mike for your help. But I used var folderName = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue(); and got the result I wanted. I need to figure out how to get this for each row now!

Comment: I have updates the answer accordingly

Comment: Got it...I was not able to check the comments so wrote the comment again. Thanks ! Will check and update!

Comment: I think OP's main issue is to create a folder based on a row without having to input specific range in the script. I recommend addng checkbox to identify what row is to be based on.

Comment: @Sarvasiddhanta Services P Ltd , pls now provide a copy of your spreadsheet to go further.

Comment: Thanks both Mike @ASyntuBU  . Will try to do it using the available information as given by ASyntuBU . WIll update later ! Thanks again.

Comment: I have completed my answer, if you want I can give you my own spreadsheet.

Comment: A better implementation as this makes the checkbox act as button itself and no need for additional button. I was fixated on the button where in actuality, it can be replaced by the checkbox itself. Also neat in adding the ID of the folder after creation. Upvoted

Comment: Thx also for your advice, the checkboxes you mentionned first was a good solution. However, I found that onEdit was not sufficient, we need an installable trigger. I have put a custom menu to activate the function https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tzYS-qX8pT90-KkKNXV9O97WGXxorvCj_VWKbH0bu6U/copy

Comment: Dear Mike, Thanks so much for your help. I will use both of your answers and work it out. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the button/shape that is assigned to the script does not hold the location where you put it. It is not bound to a cell, it is floating over it.

First thing you might think is to create multiple buttons and create a function for each button, but that is very time consuming and worse, very bad implementation.

So we have to be creative to identify which cells we'd like to process. Here is what I have thought so you can identify which row to create a folder for.

You would need to add a single column in which it identifies if the row is to be processed or not. Once a checkbox is ticked and you pressed the button, the script now loops all the rows and finds the rows in which a checkbox is ticked. Then creates a folder based on the data it held. This also allows you to create multiple folders if multiple checkboxes are ticked. See the script and images below:

#### Script:

```
function createFolder() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  values.forEach(function (row) {
    var [isTicked, serialNum, customerName] = row;
    // if column A is ticked 
    if(isTicked) {
      var name = `${serialNum}-${customerName}`;
      var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name);
      // if name generated is not existing
      if(!folders.hasNext())
        DriveApp.createFolder(name);
    }
  });
}
```

#### Sample:

[image]

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: ASyntuBu - thanks so much ! Awesome. I will try this today and update here. Really appreciate your help. Regards, Ravi